# How can I remap enitre roslaunch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have 2 real turtlebots (for now.. I'll have more in the near future) and I want them to run on one ros-master,
since they have identical topics if I launch in one turtlebot the other get it also.
for example if I launch
turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
in one and afterwards in the other it will shutdown the first and open in the last.
since that I've thought to create groups and remap the topics but since all the topics are the same it seems like allot of work.

can I remap entire launch file without remapping every topic one by one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217014/how-can-i-remap-enitre-roslaunch-file?/) by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to just export ROS_NAMESPACE to the namespace you want and launch the same file.

It might also be possible to nest the whole roslaunch in one more group, but I'm not sure how well that deals with nesting.

The main thing to look out for is that all nodes/launch parts are written properly to support nesting, i.e., not topics with / when not needed, etc.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-09-03**:
damned, you were faster ;-)

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-09-03**:
For multiple turtlebots he you should probably check out http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_concert/Tutorials/indigo/Concert%20Bringup (because of the APP stuff and so on ...)

**Comment by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) on 2015-09-04**:
Hi, thanks for the fast response! I'm new in ROS and the tutorials I've encountered so far regarded nodes, can you give me an example? I'm lauching allot of topics with:
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
how can remap this argument?
and concert is no solution for me (joint computer issues)

**Comment by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) on 2015-09-08**:
I was finally able to test the answer and it is working fine with exporting ROS_NAMESPACE before launching the launch file, is there a way to permanently set the ROS_NAMESPACE?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-08**:
You could put that into your .bashrc. However setting that permanently is usually unnecessary as then you could also just not set it. It is mostly an advantage if you want to start launches in multiple different namespaces.